# GtkSourceView in gtkmm app

Tags: gtkmm, glade, gtksourceview

I want to load a Glade file into simple Gtkmm application. Here's my code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
try {
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.helen.ide");
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("temp.glade");
    Gtk::Window* w;
    builder->get_widget("applicationwindow_ide", w);

    return app->run(*w);
}
catch(Glib::Error e) {
    printf("Error : %s\n", e.what().c_str());
    return 1;
}
}
```

But it doesn't work (it catches the error, which says that GtkSourceView is unknown for Gtk::Builder). In Glade, however, the file can be opened end edited without errors, showing "nornal" GtkSourceView.

After some time of googling, I found that the type of SourceView must be "registered in the glib's type system", but no way how it's been done in C++, only in Python.

So, what should be the corrections? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you need to install gtkmm GtkSourceView wrapping

```
sudo apt-get install libgtksourceviewmm-3.0-dev
```

then

```
#include <gtksourceviewmm.h>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've done the first, but didn't know about the second.